# Convert cron expression to range of dates using SQL

Tags: sql, cron, presto, trino

Any SQL snippets that can convert an arbitrary cron expression into a range of dates?

ie given `30-59/15 9 24-31 * */4`

create a row for each timestamp it matches up to a month in the future

Comment: That would be hard to express in SQL. I'd recommend writing an UDF in Java -- still not easy, but perhaps you can reuse a library for this.